# top-bar background color not changing with SASS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of my top-bar in Zurb Foundation 6. I want to change it from #e6e6e6 to #333333 by changing _settings.scss . I changed the following:

```
// Background color for the top bar
$topbar-bg-color: $oil;
$oil         : #333333;
```

I SASS compiled the script but the background of top-bar is still #e6e6e6.

Can someone help me?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 0):

I suppose should change the order of the variable definitions:

```
$oil         : #333333;
// Background color for the top bar
$topbar-bg-color: $oil;
```